# Arch: can't use pacman: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: pacman

I just finished installing Arch and setting up my wireless connection. I wanted to install additional packages so I tried using pacman.

But with every command I use I get the following error:

> pacman: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or library.

But in /usr/local/lib I have the following files/folders:

> libcurl.a libcurl.a libcurl.so libcurl.so.4 libcurl.so.4.2.o pkgconfig

So how do I point pacman to these files?

Comment: you can check the linked libraries by using the command `ldd` and you cand find the absolute path of an executable by using `which` for example `which bash`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why your `libcurl.*` files are in `/usr/local/lib`, but mine are in `/usr/lib` where they're supposed to be. To confirm `ldconfig` isn't finding them, use

```
ldconfig -p | grep curl
```

It shouldn't print anything, if it does, check the version number, you may have gotten the wrong version.

To rectify this, you need to tell `ldconfig` where to find the libs. You can either put a symlink from `/usr/lib` to the appropriate files in `/usr/local/lib`, or you can tell `ldconfig` to search there directly:

```
echo /usr/local/lib | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
```

Then run `sudo ldconfig` to update the cache.

And perhaps try and figure out why your libs are in the wrong directory.

Comment: Ok pacman finds libcurl now but now it doesn't find libgpgme.so.11.
I installed gnupg 2.0 but that doesn't help. But "find / -name 'libgpgme*'" doesn't even return anything. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Try the instructions [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1050732) to install `libgpgme` manually. Has it been a while since you upgraded? A few months ago (though that's  testing repos, release may have been more recent), Arch made some big upgrades to pacman, mostly for signing packages and it was a big shitshow (and I do not use the term lightly, it broke two installs of mine twice each, one wouldn't even boot). It seems to be fine after getting the new pacman up and running though.

Comment: I did that but now I get two new errors:
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.7)
/lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIB_2.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/libgpgme.1

Answer (score 3):

You need to find out where it's looking for `libcurl` (and not finding it), as it's obviously not checking `/usr/local/lib`.  First, I recommend running ldd against it to see if any other libraries are missing:

```
ldd $(which pacman)
```

I hope you have `strace` installed, because that's going to be your next tool to find out where it's looking for `libcurl` files.

```
strace  -e open -o strace.log $(which pacman)
```

After you running this, `less strace.log` and see what files it tried to open, and this will help you determine where it's looking for it.  A quick and dirty fix would be to copy (or symlink) the appropriate files from `/usr/local/lib` to where it's looking for it.

Here's what I got when I strace'd `wget`:

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/wgetrc", O_RDONLY)           = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/\"en_US/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/\"en/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/\"en_US/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/\"en/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en\"/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en\"/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```